# tkz-fct thick line in function affects draw points thickness

Tags: tkz-fct

While defining the thickness of a line plotted I've noticed that the drawn points change as well. This only happens when using the `\tkzFct` command and not `\draw`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
      \tkzInit[xmin=-3,xmax=5.5, ymin=-3, ymax=6]
      \tkzAxeXY
      \tkzDefPoints{2/5/A, 2/3/B, 5/-2/C}
      \tkzFct[domain=-1:2,thick]{x**2+1}
      \tkzDrawPoints[fill=white, size=4mm](A)
      \tkzDrawPoints[fill=black, size=4mm](B,C)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How would I have to write the instruction so that it didn't have this effect? How to change the points back to normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `scope` environment

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.6]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-3,xmax=5.5, ymin=-3, ymax=6]
    \tkzAxeXY
    \tkzDefPoints{2/5/A, 2/3/B, 5/-2/C}
    \begin{scope}
      \tkzFct[domain=-1:2,thick]{x**2+1}
    \end{scope}
    \tkzDrawPoints[fill=white, size=4mm](A)
    \tkzDrawPoints[fill=black, size=4mm](B,C)
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```